# Separate SNMP entities w/ same engineID?

Tags: pysnmp

I am using pysnmp to send notifications from an AgentX sub-agent under Net-SNMP.  For SNMPv3, I don't want to require separate USM user configurations with different engineIDs in the authentication and privacy keys to receive traps from both the main agent and my sub-agent.  Are there any issues with using the oldEngineID value from the Net-SNMP snmpd persistent config file to configure SnmpEngine in my notification dispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd effectively end up having different SNMP entities with the same engine ID. While technically feasible, this is not something SNMP standard recommends (read up on SNMP engine ID generation).

Perhaps there could be some security implications as well.

Otherwise your plan should work.

Comment: I'd like the master and sub-agent to be the same entity, in the end.